# Как лучше осуществлять клиентское подключение к серверу?

Tags: java, сокет

Я работаю над клиент-серверным приложением впервые с помощью библиотеки Netty, и если с сервером всё проще, он включился и сразу ожидает подключения, то с клиентом всё иначе в моём случае. Я не знаю, как лучше сделать запрос технической информации для работы и запрос для авторизации пользователя. Пробовал несколько вариантов и в каждом я не уверен.

1. Самый логичный и простой, который мог прийти в голову, - при запуске программы создается одно постоянное подключение, по которому сначала запрашивается техническая информация, обрабатывается и потом только, и то, если пользователь захочет, можно произвести авторизацию. Проблема только в одном, мне кажется: неизвестно сколько времени пройдет от запуска программы до авторизации и при этом всё это время подключение должно быть установлено, а если пользователь запустит много инстансов программы, то что? - куча подключений, лишняя нагрузка и тайм-аут ответа не поставишь...
2. Попытка избежать проблемы из первого пункта навела еще на мысль - устанавливать подключение и затем завершать его после завершения запроса, но этот вариант сразу отпал, т.к. нужно через это подключение еще получить ответ. Да, здесь можно поставить тайм-аут на ожидание ответа, допустим, 5 секунд и не завершать подключение вручную, и проблема с получением пакета отпадает, и появляется третья... логичнее было бы использовать уже установленное подключение, если оно еще живо, чем каждый раз создавать новое и в случае тайм-аута пересоздавать его.

В целом меня устроил бы второй вариант, но у меня проблемы с его реализацией. А что посоветуете вы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете закрывать соединение, если оно было неактивно (не использовалось) определенное количество времени. Это довольно стандартное решение, используемоме при пулинге соединений.

Comment: Об этом я и написал в конце 2 пункта, но как узнать, когда подключение было завершено по тайм-ауту, а когда оно еще живо, чтоб не создавать новое?

Comment: @BRONNER, тайм-аут соединения обычно - это время на установление соединения. Так что ваш вопрос выглядит несколько запутанным. Соединение живо, если вы его не закрыли. Хотя соединение может быть закрыто и удаленным сервером. Так что соединения нужно проверять время от времени. См. реализации существующих пулов.

Comment: @a_gura, да, я ошибся, тайм-аут чтения, конечно же, в netty это достигается с помощью данного класса http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/ReadTimeoutHandler.html